# clarificationwith unit tests and integration tests

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, tdd

I am starting out on testing.  I want to do more TDD, so I thought I will come up with some tests for a simple part of an app that I am developing.  The app requires the user to login to get access to the system, so naturally there will be a logout as well.

So I am trying to think of units tests and integration tests..

but all I seem to come up are is just integration tests

1. Login with incorrect username and password
2. Login with correct username and password
3. login with a particular user profile, and check that the correct profile has been loaded
4. logout, ensure I can't navigate to a particular page

so what would be unit tests ?

I am sure people would have written unit and integration tests for something like this before?

Answer (score 0):

Integration tests are blackbox tests. You are testing the system without the knowledge how it works internaly. You are verifying expected results on the levels where the end user comes to interaction with the system.

Unit tests are white box tests. You know how the system internally works and you want to test the units of the system separately.

In your case I would call these tests unit tests if you are calling controller's actions which are internal parts of the system.

Or integration if you are using some browser automation tests.

Comment: at the moment I haven't written any tests, I am trying to work out the tests I would need to write.  So as an example I could have login with correct username and password as both a unit test and an integration test? one just calling controllers while the other calling browser automation?  I always thought a unit test was only suppose to check just a unit? not a while controller? a controller might have 4 different helpers it calls, I thought unit tests would just validate those 4 helpers?

Comment: @user2206329 From wikipedia "unit testing is a software testing method by which individual units of source code, sets of one or more computer program modules together with associated control data, usage procedures,..." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing so it is very opinion based what is and what is not a unit test i think.

Comment: so can I ask what sort of unit tests and integration tests would you have to check login? as I am trying TDD, I need to list the tests I should have.. what would you have?

Comment: @user2206329 it depends on your requirements. I would test login with wrong/correct credentials (user name, password separately) then check expected results. You can also test input validation, logout, etc. If you are doing TDD then you have to test almost everything. I prefer business driven tests - writing tests for important things.